# How to calculate line integral if $c2$ has the range $0\le t \lt \infty$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I have to calculate the line integral for $\int_{\mathrm{C2}}F\, dr\,$ where $C2$ is given by $$\frac{(cost,sint)}{1+e^t}$$ and $0\le t \lt \infty$
Where $\vec{F} = \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\big)$.

I have no idea how to get started, I have never worked with ranges with $\infty$ before. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Using the parametrization $\varphi(t) = \dfrac{(\cos t, \sin t)}{1+e^t}$ given,
$$\int_{C_2} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_0^\infty \vec{F}(\varphi(t))\cdot \varphi'(t)\,dt = \lim_{T\to \infty} \int_0^T \vec{F}(\varphi(t))\cdot \varphi'(t)\,dt$$ so you don't need to deal with the $\infty$ until the last step when you apply the limit.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: @BrianMoehring So I already know that $\vec{F} = \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\big)$ is conservative with the potential $xye^xy+C(y)$ and $C(y)$ is a constant. I usually parametrize with an $r$ instead of $\phi$ so I have $$\int_{\mathrm{C2}}\vec{F}\, d\vec{r}\, = \phi (endpoint) - \phi(startpoint)$$.
I have $end= (\frac{cosT}{1+e^T}, \frac{sinT}{1+e^T})$ and $start= (\frac{cos0}{1+e^0}, \frac{sin0}{1+e^0}) = (\frac {1}{2}, 0)$, but how do I solve the endpoint. I'm having difficulties finding the potential too.

Comment: @BrianMoehring well I've calculated the potential and I've got $-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} +C(y)$ which is a constant.

Comment: @BrianMoehring sorry that potential was from another question, the potential I've got is as I've mentioned above. But I still don't know how to calculate the endpoint with $\infty$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm still open for explanation and answers if you have the time :)

Comment: Since $f(x,y) = -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ satisfies $\nabla f = \vec{F},$ and you have said you usually parametrize with "$r$", we have
$$\int_{C_2} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \lim_{T\to\infty} f(r(T)) - f(r(0))$$  Just substitute in the potential (no need for a $C(y)$) and the parametrization, and then evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, as pointed out in the comments, $\vec F$ is conservative, with scalar potential

$$f(x,y)=-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}+c$$

since $f_x=\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$ and $f_y=\frac y{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$.

The the integral is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_2}\vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec r&=\int_{C_2} \nabla f(x,y)\cdot\mathrm d\vec r\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}f\left(\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t},\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}\right)-\lim_{t\to0^+}f\left(\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t},\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}\right)
\end{align}$$

We have

$$\begin{align}
g(t)=f\left(\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t},\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}\right)&=-\sqrt{1-\frac{\cos^2t}{(1+e^t)^2}-\frac{\sin^2t}{(1+e^t)^2}}+c\\[1ex]
&=-\frac{\sqrt{2e^t+e^{2t}}}{1+e^t}+c\\[1ex]
&=-\frac{\sqrt{2e^{-t}+1}}{e^{-t}+1}+c
\end{align}$$

As $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(t)=-1+c$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to0^+}g(t)=-\frac{\sqrt3}2+c$, we find that the line integral has a value of $\boxed{\frac{\sqrt3}2-1}$.

---

Alternatively, you can compute the integral directly, if you feel so bold. Composing $\vec F$ with $x(t)=\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t}$ and $y(t)=\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}$ gives

$$\begin{align}
\vec F(x(t),y(t))&=\left(\frac{\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}\right)^2}},\frac{\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\cos t}{1+e^t}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sin t}{1+e^t}\right)^2}}\right)\\[1ex]
&=\frac{\sqrt{e^t(2+e^t)}}{(1+e^t)^2}(\cos t,\sin t)
\end{align}$$

and differentiating the parameterization of $C_2$ gives

$$\frac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\left(-(1+e^t)\sin t-e^t\cos t,(1+e^t)\cos t-e^t\sin t\right)}{(1+e^t)^2}$$

Now, in the integral,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_2}\vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec r&=\int_0^\infty \vec F(x(t),y(t))\cdot\frac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}\,\mathrm dt\\[1ex]
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{\frac t2}}{(1+e^t)^2\sqrt{2+e^t}}\,\mathrm dt\\[1ex]
&=-2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\cos^3v}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2v}}\,\mathrm dv&\text{where }\tan v=e^{\frac t2}\\[1ex]
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

(The precise steps for finding the [antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%5E3%28v%29%2Fsqrt%28%281%2Bcos%5E2%28v%29%29%29) elude me, but rest assured this integral has the [same value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2*%28integrate+cos%5E3%28v%29%2Fsqrt%28%281%2Bcos%5E2%28v%29%29%29+from+%CF%80%2F4+to+%CF%80%2F2%29) as found earlier.)